# Flash Builder 4.5: could not resolve X to a component implementation

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I just upgraded out Flex project to use SDK version 4.5.1.21328 and the Flash Builder to version 4.5

All of the sudden, I'm getting several red tags on the Flash Builder: "could not resolve s:State/fx:Script/whatever to a component implementation"

However, the project builds fine with Maven, and seems to work well too.

Does anyone have any information on how to remove these "problems"?

Thanks.

Comment: Flash/Flex Builder have these strange issues from the day one. Usually Clean Build resolved these issues in most cases.

Comment: Clean doesn't help, the red markers are there from the get-go and don't go anywhere with clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally managed to find a workaround. Adding

--namespace+=http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009,${flexlib}/mxml-2009-manifest.xml --namespace+=http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml,${flexlib}/mxml-manifest.xml --namespace+=library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark,${flexlib}/spark-manifest.xml

to the "Additional compiler arguments" in properties -> Flex Compiler seems to remove all the red markers.

Answer (score 1):

Great tip. Error I was getting was:

```
Could not resolve <mx:RichTextEditor> to a component implementation.
```

I had to add the above settings and do the following to get mine to compile.

Here's what I did:
project properties->Flex Build->Path-> Library path tab. press Add SWC...
add C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4.5/sdks/4.5.1/frameworks/libs/mx/mx.swc

Then in the Source Path tab press add folder navigate to:
C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4.5/sdks/4.5.1/frameworks/projects/mx/src

then add in the namespaces as listed in the above article. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Clean.

Just as the commenter said, usually just a strange Flash Builder bug. If Project -> Clean... doesn't fix it, comment or revise question.

Answer (score 0):

Your batch builder might be using a different set of library files than the IDE. Look in Project | Properties under Build Path and see what version of the SDK it's using.